# Use Clojure to create symlink

Tags: scripting, clojure, symlink

I've been focusing on Clojure recently as a possible functional language to do systems scripting. Until, it dawned on me that having the JVM underneath means I'm limited to Java's capability.

So, how do I create a symlink? Or a hard link? I mean without `(sh "ln" ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, this is indeed a pain. I'm not sure the `sh` option is all that bad, actually... Having said that, Ant provides a symlink task which you could use in a reasonably Clojure-friendly way through Lancet, the Ant wrapper originally introduced by Stuart Halloway in his "Programming Clojure" book and currently used internally by Leiningen. If you want to see the symlink task in action in Leiningen, have a look at [this line](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/b93f5e4feb1fcb7465c02bfbc83177050bfe84b3/src/leiningen/deps.clj#L24) in the 1.3.0 release.

Comment: Also see how [the future might be better](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/javadoc/java/nio/file/Path.html).

Comment: I suppose every language has its warts.

Comment: Oh bother, now I'm not sure if the symlinking in lein even *works*... I suppose one ought to view this as an opportunity to test one's inner calm.

Comment: Oh my! I see that, in the Path class, we might get an `isHidden` method. Does this imply the ability to create hidden files…? At last? The future is bright. (sorry to stray off topic…) I think the `sh` option might be your best bet; symlinks aren't really x-platform, thus the lack of support in Java.

Comment: [Here](http://www.onyxbits.de/content/blog/patrick/how-deal-filesystem-softlinkssymbolic-links-java) is a nice write-up on how to distinguish symlinks from regular files in Java through JNI. By the way, I never got the "symlinks aren't portable" idea. At least an `.isSymbolicLink` method would be entirely cross-platform (returning `false` if the platform hosting the file does not support symlinks in the first place and maybe throwing an exception if for some reason it cannot discover the right answer), right? (Java can be exasperating.)

Comment: Totally agree. It is aggravating, and it's the same rationale behind not supporting creating hidden files. Silly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna/) to access native libs on the target host.

Simple example:

```
(ns jna-test
    (:import 
     (com.sun.jna Native Function)))

 (defn symlink [oldpath newpath]
    (-> (Function/getFunction "c" "symlink")
    (.invoke Integer (to-array [oldpath newpath]))))
```

There are also Clojure wrappers awailable:
[clj-native](http://github.com/bagucode/clj-native) and
[clojure-jna](http://github.com/Chouser/clojure-jna)

Answer (score 0):

It's something of a side note:

when using Clojure for system commands, if you use [cake](http://github.com/ninjudd/cake) instead of leiningen it can use a persistent JVM so you dont have to wait three seconds for the JVM to start every time you run a command.

*cake is not very stable so some days it works much better than others. (as of Sep. 2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of this library https://github.com/ToBeReplaced/nio.file which works for me

```
(require '[org.tobereplaced.nio.file :refer [create-symbolic-link! ] :as nio])

(defn createSimLink [ targetPath newLink ]
  (let [theName (.getName (File. targetPath))]
    (try
      (nio/create-symbolic-link!  (str  newLink "/" theName)  targetPath  )
      (catch Exception e (prn "error " e)))))

(createSimLink "c:/tmp/test.txt" "c:/tmp/myFolder")
```

Note related privilege is needed. E.g. to run it in Windows 7 in Emacs/Cider environment, the emacs needs to be started from an admin command window, otherwise it will complain "FileSystemException java.nio.file.FileSystemException: c:\tmp\myFolder\test.txt: A required privilege is not held by the client"

Answer (score 0):

```
(require '[clojure.java.io :as io])
(import '[java.nio.file Files Paths]
        '[java.nio.file.attribute FileAttribute])

(def user-home (System/getProperty "user.home"))
(def user-pwd (System/getProperty "user.dir"))

(defn path [p]
  (let [expanded (.replaceFirst p "^~" user-home)]
    (Paths/get expanded (make-array String 0))))

(defn symlink
  [link target & attrs]
  (let [link-path (path link)
        target-path (path (.getPath (io/file user-pwd target)))]
    (Files/createSymbolicLink link-path target-path (into-array FileAttribute attrs))))
```

That's what I came up with.